# How to convert String Array to php Array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-livewire

**How to convert Sting Array to PHP Array?**

`"['a'=>'value one','key2'=>'value two']"`

to

`$data=['a'=>'value one','key2'=>'value two'];`

### Please let me know if anyone knows of any solution

---

I want to take array input via textarea. And I want to convert that to a PHP array.

When I'm through textarea

`['a'=>'value one','key2'=>'value two']`

This is happening after submitting the from

`"['a'=>'value one','key2'=>'value two']"`

Now how do I convert from this to PHP Array?

Comment: What actually you are doing ? How you are getting this string ? May be We can suggest you better way of doing it.

Comment: Agreed with @JohnDoe  let us know from where you are getting that string. You will get better help

Comment: I want to take array input via textarea. And I want to convert that to a PHP array.

When I'm through textarea
`['a'=>'value one','key2'=>'value two'] `

This is happening after submitting the form

`"['a'=>'value one','key2'=>'value two']"`

Now how do I convert from this to PHP Array?

Comment: You can change the above array string to Javascript JSON and then decode it in PHP.

Comment: @IQBALHASAN  please show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I got it....thank's @Nikita

Comment: @WM-SH-PD-TV-FC Thanks for helping me with your important time. I've already got my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are not allowing multi dimensional arrays, this will work:

```
$stringArray = "['a'=>'value one','key2'=>'value two']";
$array = array();

$trimmedStringArray = trim( $stringArray, '[]' );
$splitStringArray = explode( ',', $trimmedStringArray );
foreach( $splitStringArray as $nameValuePair ){
    list( $key, $value ) = explode( '=>', $nameValuePair );
    $array[$key] = $value;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    ['a'] => 'value one'
    ['key2'] => 'value two'
)
```

You will probably want to do some error checking to make sure the input is in the correct format before you process the input.

Comment: it's working. But if the syntax is wrong, PHP error is coming. How do I check if the syntax is correct or not? –

Comment: What error are you seeing? I tested it here: https://3v4l.org/KDisl

Comment: I see, it depends on what format you would like to accept input in. If you want to strictly enforce the format that you described above, you can match with a regular expression like this: `if( !preg_match( "/^\[?('[^']+'=>'[^']+',?)+\]?$/", $stringArray )    print 'invalid input';`

Answer (score 0):

Extremely unsafe version using eval():

```
<?php

$a = "['a'=>'value one','key2'=>'value two']";

eval('$b = '.$a.';');

print('<pre>');
print_r($b);
```

Use only when you are sure, that other people can't use your textarea input!

Using replacements to convert this to json is a much better option for public forms. Additionally, if you use this at your work, you probably would get fired :)

With syntax error catch:

```
<?php

$a = "['a'=>'value one','key2'=>'value two'dsbfbtrg]";

try {
    eval('$b = '.$a.';');
} catch (ParseError $e) {
    print('Bad syntax');
    die();
    // or do something about the error
}

print('<pre>');
print_r($b);
```

Comment: it's working. But if the syntax is wrong, PHP error is coming. How do I check if the syntax is correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
<?php
$string = "['a'=>'value one','key2'=>'value two']";
$find = ["'", "=>", "[", "]"];
$replace = ["\"", ":", "{", "}"];
$string = str_replace($find, $replace, $string);
$array = json_decode($string, true);
var_dump($array);
?>
```